# How do I use standalone Header in react-navigation with react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a standalone Header that I made:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Appbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";
import { LanguageContext } from "../contexts/LanguageContext";
import localeSelect from "../services/localeSelect";
import { title } from "../data/locales";

function Header() {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { language } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  return (
    <Appbar.Header>
      <Appbar.Action icon="menu" />
      {!user && (
        <>
          <Appbar.Content
            title={localeSelect(language, title)}
            color="#ffffff"
          />
          <Appbar.Action
            icon="login"
            color="#ffffff"}
          />
          <Appbar.Action icon="account-plus" color="#ffffff" />
        </>
      )}
      {user && (
        <>
          <Appbar.Content
            title={localeSelect(language, title)}
            color="#ffffff"
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Appbar.Header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

However, I have been struggling to find a way to connect it to my Stack.Navigator in the main component:

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { View } from "react-native";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import GameNotes from "./components/GameNotes";
import { UserContext } from "./contexts/UserContext";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function ComponentContainer() {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Header />
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          {user ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={GameNotes} />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          )}

          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because the header isn't nested in the Stack.Navigator. You also cannot nest it in the Stack.Navigator, because it only accepts Stack.Screen as children.

I've also tried using RootNavigation as a way to do this, but have failed with that as well. So what exactly am I supposed to be doing to use this Header to navigate my app?

Comment: So you want to change something in the `Stack.Navigator` when some action happens in the `Header`? Most likely what you need is to pass a callback to the `Header` component from the `ComponentContainer`, which `Header` will call when a user clicks something. Inside this callback you can modify your state in order to change the `Stack.Navigator` or take some other action. The callback will be defined inside `ComponentContainer`.

Comment: I won't even pretend that I understand exactly what you mean by this. Could you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change something in the `Stack.Navigator` when some action happens in the `Header`? Most likely what you need is to pass a callback to the `Header` component from the `ComponentContainer`, which `Header` will call when a user clicks something. Inside this callback you can modify your state in order to change the `Stack.Navigator` or take some other action. The callback will be defined inside `ComponentContainer`.

I'm not exactly sure how this all works in `react-native`, but in React this is what it might look like:
**Header:**

```
// Imports

function Header(onPressCallback) {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { language } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  return (
    <Appbar.Header>
      <Appbar.Action icon="menu" onPress={() => onPressCallback('menu')}  />
      // Other Header items
    </Appbar.Header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

**ComponentContainer:**

```
// Imports

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const onPressHandler = (headerItemName) => {
    // Do something in response to a user clicking on the "menu" icon for example
    // Maybe something like change the route on the Stack (don't know this API)
}

export default function ComponentContainer() {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Header onPressCallback={onPressHandler}  />
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          {user ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={GameNotes} />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          )}

          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is how you usually handle interactions between two siblings components, the parent component passes a callback to one, so that the first child can notify when something happened, and then the parent takes action by changing the state for the second child to respond to.